# Dictionary mapping python

Tags: python-3.x

Here's my code:
Create a class, rit_object is a private class than has types for the parameters:

```
class YearCount(rit_object):
    __slots__ = ( 'year', 'count')
    _types = (int, int)
```

Returned a YearCount object:

```
def createYearCount(year, count):
    return YearCount(year, count)
```

Read through file. the output should resemble:

```
import wordData
words = wordData.readWordFile(’very_short.csv’)
print(words)
{’airport’: [YearCount( year=2007, count=175702 ), YearCount( year=2008,
count=173294 )], ’wandered’: [YearCount( year=2005, count=83769 ),
YearCount( year=2006, count=87688 ), YearCount( year=2007, count=108634 ),
YearCount( year=2008, count=171015 )], ’request’: [YearCount( year=2005,
count=646179 ), YearCount( year=2006, count=677820 ), YearCount( year=2007,
count=697645 ), YearCount( year=2008, count=795265 )]}
```

readWordFile(fileName):

```
def readWordFile(fileName):
    #read in the entire unigram dataset

    words = {}
    for line in fileName:
        new = line.split(', ')
        print(new)
        id = new[0]
        print(id)
        yc = createYearCount(int(new[1]), int(new[2]))
        # add to list or create a new list
        if not id in words:
            words[id] = [yc]
        else:
            words[id].append(yc)
    print(words)
```

if my total occurrences  uses 'words' from my readWordFile, is my totaloccurences function working corrctly to produces the total count for each year?

```
def totalOccurences(word, words):
    count = 0
    if words[id] == word:
        count += YearCount.count
    return count
```

text file:

```
airport, 2007, 175702
airport, 2008, 173294
request, 2005, 646179
request, 2006, 677820
request, 2007, 697645
request, 2008, 795265
wandered, 2005, 83769
wandered, 2006, 87688
wandered, 2007, 108634
wandered, 2008, 171015
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `totalOccurences` you're using the variable `id` but it isn't defined anywhere in the function itself: `if words[id] == word`. I think what you meant to do is sum all the word counts within `words[word]`. So the function would become:

```
def totalOccurences(word, words):
    if word not in words:
        return 0
    count = 0
    for item in words[word]:
        count += item.count
    return count
```

If the word doesn't exist in `words` then the function simply returns 0. Otherwise, it'll go over the elements in `words[word]` (which is a list) and it'll add up all the `.count` values. That will then give you the total number of occurrences of `word` in `words[word]`.